# datatables jeditable validate input url how to combine this code?

Tags: validation, datatables, jeditable

I'm using datatables with the jeditable plugin, I have it setup to update directly to mysql, I need to validate some input fields to make sure a URL is being inserted. I have this code which validates jeditable fields (see jsfiddle) I need some help to integrate the jsfiddle with the table initializing code. I can add the onsubmit no problem but not sure how to add this part into my .makeEditable function, any help's appreciated thanks.

```
$('#url').editable(function(valurl) {
    // Do your own stuff here...
    return valurl;
},
```

http://jsfiddle.net/peter/CLuvp/

And my datatable is initialized with

```
var oTable3;
$(document).ready(function() {
            oTable3 = $('#table3').dataTable( {
        "sDom":'t<"bottom"ifpl><"clear">',
        "bAutoWidth": false,
        "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
            "aoColumns": [ 
            { "bSortable": false},
            null,
            null,
            null,
            null
            ]

    } 
    ).makeEditable({
        sUpdateURL: "<?=$this->siteUrl()?>profiles/updatevalue",
        "aoColumns": [null,
                    null,
                    {
                        type: 'text',
                        submit:'Ok',
                        cancel:'Cancel',
                        width: "100px"

                    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can simply include the options for each column in the `aoColumns` option, e.g.:

```
.makeEditable({
    sUpdateURL: "<?=$this->siteUrl()?>profiles/updatevalue",
    "aoColumns": [null, null,
    {
        submit: 'Save',
        width: 200,
        placeholder: 'Enter URL...',
        onblur: 'submit',
        onsubmit: function() {...}
    }]
});
```

A cleaner way (or the aforementioned simply doesn't work) would be to use the `url` rule in that column:

```
.makeEditable({
    sUpdateURL: "<?=$this->siteUrl()?>profiles/updatevalue",
    "aoColumns": [null, null,
    {
        submit: 'Save',
        width: 200,
        placeholder: 'Enter URL...',
        onblur: 'submit',
        cssclass: 'url'
    }]
});
```

See [this demo](http://jquery-datatables-editable.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/inline-validation.html) for more details.

Comment: jeditable is working, I have options setup for each of my columns I just omitted most of the code for sake of keeping the question short. I was having difficulty integrating the jsfiddle with my .makeEditable code I posted which validates that a URL is entered into the text input box of the editable field. I know how to add the onsubmit into each of my column options as needed but i'm not sure how to setup the code below with mine to work right$('#url').editable(function(valurl) {
    // Do your own stuff here...
    return valurl;
},

Comment: Then do you actually want to post the data to `sUpdateURL`?

Comment: If the input validates as a URL yes continue posting to sUpdate

Comment: OK. So you check for that in your `onSubmit` function, right? Why do you need this bit: `$('#url').editable(function(valurl) { // Do your own stuff here... return valurl; },`?

Comment: I had found the code for validating the URL I don't know how to integrate it with my table initialization code. So I don't know whether I need that bit or not. An example would help

Comment: Have you tried the 2nd approach proposed above using `cssclass`? `cssclass` doesn't specify a CSS class, but a validation rule. I believe `url` is one of the in-built ones in the jQuery Validation plugin. Take a look at the demo provided.

Comment: I didn't realize the demo on datatables was for validation, I thought you were pointing out how to setup the columns. Should work thanks